# libgdx box2d player arm towards touch

Tags: android, rotation, libgdx, box2d, angle

Okay, i have my player with an arm connected with revolute joint. And what i want is the arm body rotate towards the touch point.

[image]

I have tried to calculate the angle of the touch point to the body, and set the arm with

```
setTransform(armBody.getPosition(), angle);
```

but it acts weird on the update method. It's rotating around the center of the arm body and not around the body, where the revolute joint connects.

I was also thinking about a joint, but i don't know which could work like i want.

I would appreciate any help!

Comment: I would use a revolute joint to pin the upper end of the arm in place, and ApplyTorque to turn the arm body.

Comment: Thank you man, i have found your tutorial which helped a lot. I could finally make it, and it behaves perfectly. If you make it as an answer i will accept it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a revolute joint to pin the upper end of the arm in place, and ApplyTorque to turn the arm body.